# msql query or mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

This is a performance question.

Lets say I have the following mysql data (over 1,000 records of the same structure)

table name:  hours

```
Employee | Hours | Scope    |  Project
 John        4      labour        projId_A
 John        3      Travel        projId_A
 Mark        4      labour        projId_A
 Mark        2      Travel        projId_A
```

Is it better performance if I do one query with the summaries of labour and travel to get this

table name: projects  (i would left join projects and hours)

```
Project  |  labourHrs  |  travelHrs
projId_A      8             5
```

or us is it better to

1. create a view that shows only labourHrs
2. create a view that shows only travelHrs

Then create 2 joints projects -> labourH and projects -> travelH

to get:

```
Project  |  labourHrs  |  travelHrs
projId_A      8             5
```

i guess i am asking, is it better performance to do the sum inside the project query or inside the labour_view & travel_view'

any thoughts?

Comment: In my experience, VIEWS never help performance (other than perhaps reducing the likelihood of others making poorer versions of the same query); they also tend to make debugging much harder as MySQL does not just "join" the results as if they were a table, it tries to integrate the queries behind them with the query the view is being used in, and not always in expected ways. (Simple example: a `SELECT * FROM aTable` query as a view called "view1", will not first select everything from `aTable` if you do `SELECT * FROM view1 WHERE id = 1`; it will run the underlying query with the condition.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to do a single query:

```
select project
       sum(case when score = 'labour' then hours else 0 end) as labourHrs,
       sum(case when score = 'travel' then hours else 0 end) as travelhours
from t
group by project;
```

From a performance perspective in MySQL, views do not improve performance.  They might not affect performance, but they won't make it better.

Comment: They're faster if you can materialize them, but unfortunately MySQL does not have this feature.

Comment: The only reason that i am thinking of a view is because i am dealing with quickBooks timecards which they keep the hours like this:  PT3H30M.  Which means i need to substring() the PT,H,M to get the numbers (3, 30).   so, where i have "hours" i need to deal with "PT3H30M".  I want to see if i create views that substrings() the PT3H30M, will negativly affect performance.   does that make sense?

Comment: @user2062455  . . . Single column transformations are fine for a view.  Feel free to define a view to extract the hours from that column.

Answer (score 0):

Views are generally used to hide data or simplify a query.  Use your first option and do the SUM in the initial SQL.